# Multiple if elif conditions to be evaluated for each row of pyspark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I need help in pyspark dataframe topic.
I have a dataframe of say 1000+ columns and 100000+ rows.Also I have 10000+ if elif conditions are there,under each if else condition there are few global variables getting incremented by some values.
Now my question is how can I achieve this in pyspark only.
I read about filter and where functions which return rows based on condition by I need to check those 10000+ if else conditions and perform some manipulations.

Any help would be appreciated.

If you could give an example with small dataset that would be of great help.

Thankyou

Comment: Please provide an overview of what you have already tried and possibly the condition that you want to implement on some toy problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function to contain all of you if elif conditions, then apply this function into each row of the DataFrame.

Just use `.rdd` to convert the DataFrame to a normal RDD, then use `map()` function.
e.g, `DF.rdd.map(lambda row: func(row))`

Hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you just want to update some global counters while iterating over your DataFrame. For this, you need to:

#### 1) Define one or more [accumulators](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/programming-guide.html#accumulators):

```
ac_0 = sc.accumulator(0)
ac_1 = sc.accumulator(0)
```

#### 2) Define a function to update your accumulators for a given row, e.g:

```
def accumulate(row):
    if row.foo:
        ac_0.add(1)
    elif row.bar:
        ac_1.add(row.baz)
```

#### 3) Call `foreach` on your DataFrame:

```
df.foreach(accumulate)
```

#### 4) Inspect the accumulator values

```
> ac_0.value
>>> 123
```